# Will Google consider it duplicate content if we re-publish our previously accidentally deleted content on a new URL?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing

Around 100 pages of our website got deleted accidentally due to the programming mistake.  They then got deindexed from Google, since those pages were not accessible to Google for about a month.

Now, We want to republish the pages again with different URL.  Will Google consider this as a duplicated content if republished again using different URLs?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. The pages aren't live on your site, nor are they in Google's index. 
There's no way it can be considered as duplicate.

Is there a reason you want to use a different URL? If you do, implement some 301s to the new URLs.